# How to get substring between right-to-left (Arabic) word and a tag using php?

Tags: php, substring, arabic, right-to-left, strpos

I am trying to get substring between two strings that starts with Arabic word `تفاحة` and ends with `--------------------------------------<br>`

My current code works well for finding substring between two English words but fails if starting word is Arabic. Could any one help me how to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

```
<?

$returned_content = get_data('./input.php');

$SearchWord_Value = $_GET['SearchWord'];

/* gets the data from a URL */
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}

$parsed = get_string_between($returned_content, $SearchWord_Value, '--------------------------------------<br>');

echo "<br><br>Found Block:<br>".$parsed;

?>
```

Full string example to get data between two strings:

```
تفاحة:
<br><img src="http://asite.com/1.jpg"><br>
<a href="https://asite.com/1.html">تفاحة</a> <br />

<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link1 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link2 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link3 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link4 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link5 </a> <br />

--------------------------------------<br>
```

**Edit:**
This is new sample input:

```
$str = <<<'STR'
&#1578;&#1601;&#1575;&#1581;&#1577;:
<br><img src="http://asite.com/1.jpg"><br>
<a href="https://asite.com/1.html">&#1578;&#1601;&#1575;&#1581;&#1577;</a> <br />

<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link1 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link2 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link3 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link4 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link5 </a> <br />

--------------------------------------<br>
Mango:
<br><img src="http://asite.com/1.jpg"><br>
<a href="https://asite.com/Mango.html">Mango</a> <br />

<a href="http://asite.com/linkMango.html">link1Mango </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkMango.html">link2Mango </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkMango.html">link3Mango </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkMango.html">link4Mango </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkMango.html">link5Mango </a> <br />

--------------------------------------<br>
&#1582;&#1608;&#1582;:
<br><img src="http://asite.com/1.jpg"><br>
<a href="https://asite.com/1.html">&#1582;&#1608;&#1582;</a> <br />

<a href="http://asite.com/linkpeach.html">link1&#1582;&#1608;&#1582; </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkpeach.html">link2&#1582;&#1608;&#1582; </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkpeach.html">link3&#1582;&#1608;&#1582; </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkpeach.html">link4&#1582;&#1608;&#1582; </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/linkpeach.html">link5&#1582;&#1608;&#1582; </a> <br />

--------------------------------------<br>
STR;

$start = '&#1578;&#1601;&#1575;&#1581;&#1577;:';
$end = '--------------------------------------<br>';

//var_dump(get_string_between($str, $start, $end));

$parsed2 = get_string_between($str, $start, $end);

echo "found :".$parsed2;
```

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with UTF-8 character encoding, there is a [RTL marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) which denotes how proceeding characters are grouped when rendered on the screen, as in from right-to-left, which is encoded by `U+200F`. This only matters to how the characters are displayed on the screen, but not necessarily how they're stored in memory.

So for example, despite the fact that your characters appear from left-to-right on your screen as the `ة` being first, if we were to break the string up into characters, you'd find the `ت` actually appears first in the string and the `:` (*colon*) appears last.

```
$str = 'تفاحة:';

for($i = 0, $n = mb_strlen($str); $i < $n; $i++) {
    var_dump(mb_substr($str, $i, 1));
}
/*
output would be...

string(2) "ت"
string(2) "ف"
string(2) "ا"
string(2) "ح"
string(2) "ة"
string(1) ":"
*/
```

So you aren't actually trying to extract substrings right-to-left vs. left-to-right since all the characters in the string are just ordered bytes, and PHP doesn't care how they're displayed on your screen.

Also, note that you should be using the [multibyte versions of string functions](http://php.net/ref.mbstring) when dealing with multibyte encodings such as `mb_strpos` instead of `strpos` and `mb_substr` instead of `substr`.

Another way to refactor your function so that it works well with with both multibyte and singlebyte substring search could be to just turn the search pattern into a regular expression and rely on the regular expression search to extract your desired substring instead. This means relying the [`u` UTF-8 Pattern Modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) in your pattern.

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end) {
   // make sure we escape all parts of the pattern
    $start = preg_quote($start, '/');
    $end= preg_quote($end, '/');

    // create the pattern
    $pattern = "/$start(.*?)$end/su"; // using s and u pattern modifiers

    if (preg_match($pattern, $string, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    }
}


$str = <<<'STR'
تفاحة:
<br><img src="http://asite.com/1.jpg"><br>
<a href="https://asite.com/1.html">تفاحة</a> <br />

<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link1 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link2 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link3 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link4 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link5 </a> <br />

--------------------------------------<br>
STR;

$start = 'تفاحة:';
$end = '--------------------------------------<br>';

var_dump(get_string_between($str, $start, $end));

/*
output

string(380) "

<br><img src="http://asite.com/1.jpg"><br>
<a href="https://asite.com/1.html">تفاحة</a> <br />


<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link1 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link2 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link3 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link4 </a> <br />
<a href="http://asite.com/link.html">link5 </a> <br />

"

*/
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . I tried to use your method but unfortunately it out puts the whole returned_content content instead of the block i wanted!How to use variable inside pattern ? i want to use get method variable inside it.

Comment: Please take a look at my edit. I've refactored your function to work more accordingly with your requirements. Try using the updated version of the `get_string_between()` function in my answer and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: i used your version of get_string_between and i came up with no data at all :$parsed2 = get_string_between2($returned_content, $SearchWord_Value, '--------------------------------------<br>');
echo "<br><br>Found Block:<br>".$parsed2;

Comment: Then there was no match found or the content supplied in your example doesn't match what you have in `$returned_content`, possibly. Notice the regular expression expects the `$end` argument of that function to be the end of subject anchor. Perhaps you have a line feed at the end of your input? Notice it works as expected in the given example using your sample input.

Comment: The data stored in .input.php and it has few blocks of data similar to تفاحة but i want to block that start with word تفاحة! I even changed the input.data to only include تفاحة block and still i get no data !

Comment: Right, if the `$string` argument supplied to `get_string_between()` was `=== 'تفاحة'` it would be pretty obvious why that function would return nothing since it's looking for any characters between the `$start` and `$end` arguments. As demonstrated by the sample input I've given in that example, you can clearly see that it returns all characters between the `$start` and `$end` arguments of `$string`. Perhaps you want to update your question with the exact input that did not provide your expected result? *There's no reason to expect the input 'تفاحة ' to return anything from this function.*

Comment: **Note:** if you don't want the search string anchored just remove the circumflex `^` and `$` anchors from the expression.

Comment: I updated the input data on my first post . For given تفاحة i get the whole block of data instead of just تفاحة block! How to solve that problem. I want to the data until first occurrence of --------------------------------------<br> Thanks

Comment: OK, so remove the anchros and use non-greedy dot all. Here's an example http://phplab.io/lab/Q3cto

Comment: Thanks that help me alot but why when i pass the search term via php get method the script fails ? $start = $_GET['SearchWord'].":";

Comment: I have no idea, since you did not explain what __fails__ means here. What did you expect it to do versus what did it actually do? You also don't provide the supplied value of `$_GET['SearchWord']` for me to be able to even gander a guess as to what may have possibly gone wrong. Not enough information to help you.

Comment: When i said script fails means i get no data if i pass تفاحة via url like this : script.php?SearchWord=تفاحة or script.php?SearchWord=خوخ where $start =$_GET['SearchWord'];

Comment: Sorry, "_i get no data_" is not a useful metric by which I can help you debug your problem. Given that the correctness of the solution has been proven by the example above, using the requirements you stated, and the input you supplied, I can only deduce that the problem you are experiencing exists solely as a result of something else you did of which I am not aware. At this stage you have exceeded the scope of the question and have begun engaging in peer-to-peer debug session. This is not the purpose of StackOverflow. Please see [the help center on mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)